# How to add a data to dataframe from data matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, datamatrix

I have a data frame which name is thumb_df. It has headers in every column and counts 3000. I produced needed to log2 and then quantile normalize it. And for that, I assigned the thumb_df to data_mat which is a data matrix then make the 0 cells 1 so they cannot give -inf when I log2 after that I normalized the result and name it data_norm. Right now data_norm has no header so I need to assign it back to thumb_df or put the thumb_df headers to data_norm.
How should I do that?

```
thumb_df 
data_mat <- as.matrix(thumb_df[,-1]) 
data_mat[data_mat == 0] <- 1

data_log2 <- log2(data_mat)
data_norm <- normalize.quantiles(data_log2, copy = TRUE) # quatile 
normalization
```

I would be grateful if you can help about that. Thank you.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: `colnames(data_norm) <- colnames(thumb_df)[-1]`. And if you want or need a dataframe, `data_norm <- as.data.frame(data_norm)`.

Comment: this is my thumb_df
         X    X3     X14     X8 ..........
    1  12   10      22       15
    2  5     1        9         86

this is my data_norm
    1  1.22   2.9   8.3    2
    2  2         0      5      4 

As you can see I do not have the headers in the data_norm

Comment: Rul Barradas I did not know that is the way thx it worked.
How do you know those kinds of staff R is way more different than regular software development is there any source I can learn that kind of stuff ???